# Pycharm Debugger does not allow to jump into specific functions

Tags: python, pycharm

Suppose I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(np.arange(1,25)).reshape(4,6)

def useless_fct():
    return None

arr1.__getitem__(1)
useless()
```

Suppose further that I set a breakpoint at the line containing the getitem-call.
Now, if I want to jump into the function in debug mode - the function is just skipped, i.e. I don't get to see the getitem-call. Whereas a jump into the execution of the useless function works. Can someone explain to me why this happens? Is it because the function is maybe implemented in C?

Comment: set breakpoint in the getitem as well